# decompose conditional statement **(isset($a) && (($b && $c) || $d || $e))**

Tags: php

```
**(isset($a) && (($b && $c) || $d || $e))**  i want to refactor above conditional statement.
```

but i dont know how to proceed.
  i did some work on that first i minimized all conditional statement  into formats of variables.
  whole statement i put into if clause and i am expection true from that statement. 
  i already try to decompose into function like

```
function check($a) {
    if (!isset($a)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($e == false) {
        return true;
    }

    if ($b && $c) {
        return true;
    }

    if ($d) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

but i am sure that their might be some more better way to do this.
 can anybody help me in this.

Comment: `$b $c $d $e` don't exist in your function. Also, the original condition looks fine to me. Why make it more complicated by creating a function for it?

Comment: sorry for improper explanation of question $b $c $d $e will be some constant conditions i want to make it more simpler so that later or in future i can easily add more and more conditions to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want a compact conditional statement as in the code (with $e == false) below just add a "not" operator which is "!".

```
<?php
 function foo(mix $a, bool $b, bool $c, bool $d, bool $e){
  return isset($a) && ($b && $c) || $d || !$e);
 }
?>
```

Or the other way around..

```
<?php
 function foo(mix $a, bool $b, bool $c, bool $d, bool $e){
  if(isset($a)){
    if($b && $c){
      return true;
    } elseif($d){
      return true;
    } elseif(!$e){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
 }
?>
```

There is also an *else* statement which is executed if none of the **if** and **elseif** do not evaluate to *true*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. you made this a lot clearer for me.

Comment: Just keep in mind that one-lining code is much faster in execution and is faster to read for people. Its not that difficult to understand just use it and you'll get a hold on it eventually.